# Firebase data object access

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I am trying to make a dynamic list of buttons that correspond to sports the user can select to add to his/her profile. So I have an array of sports and then see if they are already in the user's database and if so I remove it. But my problem is that I end up with all the sports as the console prints that all of them are undefined. I'm pretty sure my problem is that each sport in the array is a string and normally when you access part of an object from the database you just add a . and the category you want. The value is not normally a string ie (userData.Spikeball as opposed to what it is doing now userData."Spikeball"). But, I dont know how else to store the values in the array to get them to work. I tried removing the quotations (which is dumb I know but you gotta try everything), and that definitely didnt work as they were then variables and not initialized. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getNewSports(uid)
{
    console.log("uid = " + uid);
    var sports = ["Spikeball", "Soccer", "Basketball", "Indoor", "Tennis", "Golf", "Frisbee", "Handball"];
    userRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users").child(uid).child("Sports");
    userRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var userData = snapshot.val();
        for(var i = 0; i < sports.length; i++)
        {
            var sport = sports[i];
            console.log("userData." + sport + " = " + userData.sport);
            if(userData.sport != null)
            {
                console.log("removing " + sport + " because userData." + sport + " = " + userData.sport);
                sports.splice(i, (i+1));
                i--;
            }

        }
        for(var i = 0; i < sports.length; i++)
        {
            var newItem = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var t = document.createTextNode(sports[i]);
            newItem.appendChild(t);
            newItem.id = sports[i];
            //newItem.class = "btn btn-secondary sportItem";
            newItem.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-secondary sportItem");
            newItem.setAttribute("onclick", "addSport(this.id)");
            document.getElementById("sports-pop-up").appendChild(newItem);
        }
        console.log(sports);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues to say the least here:

```
userRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    const userData = snapshot.val();
    console.log(userData); // -- check the list of sports returned from Firebase.
```

You can use forEach on the snapshot to loop through the result:

```
snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    const obj = snap.val();
    console.log(obj)
}
```

You are using the same for loop twice and thus you can combine the logic into one in:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sports.length; i++) {
    ... Your logic 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the forEach method is a great solution